# Compute absolute power spectrum in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, eeg

I have EEG signals. Is there a way to compute the absolute power spectrum in MATLAB within a frequency band? I know I have to use the fft function but I can't find any details about the absolute power spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Signal Processing Toolbox, you can use pwelch. If you do >>help pwelch   There will be some other choices. Try a few. Only you have your data so only you can determine if your results are acceptable

If you don't have the Toolbox, using FFT isn't hard. It's a matter of the length of your data, window choice, overlap, and a few other parameters

Comment: I'm still lost. I don't know how to use fft because I need to compute it within a frequency band.

Comment: The simplest thing is to calculate the full fft over all the frequencies and just use the ones in the bands you want. Your signal is sampled at some frequency f. If you do an N point FFT, the bins are spaced f/N

Answer (score 0):

As i could not use comment yet, i write my answer here.

you should check this link, it has explanation and code.

[link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/power-spectral-density-estimates-using-fft.html)

And you could simply create a new variable which have frequency content of your band data and then calculate the  absolute power spectrum for the newly created variable.